# Proc format variable format not showing up

Tags: sas, format

I am trying to apply format to a variable in a data set, but after running the data step, I am still only seeing the raw values ( eg -1) instead of formatted values( eg -1=INAPPLICABLE). minimal re-producible code example below. Any help at all greatly appreciated.

```
  proc format library=PUFLIB;
  '-1' = '-1 INAPPLICABLE'
  '1' = '1 YES'
  '2' = '2 NO'
  '3' = '3 DOES NOT WORK'
    ;
run;
  data example_ds;
   FORMAT ACCDNWRK $ACCDNWRK_FMT.;
input accdnwrk $;
datalines;
1
2
3
-1
;
```

Comment: You have left out the name of the format you are trying to define in the PROC FORMAT step you posted.  Is the variable in your real data numeric or character?  Perhaps you read it with something like PROC IMPORT and it created a numeric variable since the values all look like numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure to review your log.

It shows that the error is right after your `PROC FORMAT` statement. In this case you're missing the code that tells you SAS if the format is a `informat` or `format` and the format name.

```
 70         
 71          proc format library=PUFLIB;
 72           '-1' = '-1 INAPPLICABLE'
              ____
              180
 ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
 73           '1' = '1 YES'
 74           '2' = '2 NO'
 75           '3' = '3 DOES NOT WORK'
 76             ;
 NOTE: The previous statement has been deleted.
 77         run;

 NOTE: PROCEDURE FORMAT used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Adding in `value` to indicate it's a format and then the format name, accwrk_fmt is what's needed.

```
proc format library=puflib;
value accwrk_fmt
*rest of your code*
```

Comment: Note that format names do not end in a period, The period is needed when using the format.  And it should match the one used in the data step.  `$ACCDNWRK_FMT`

Comment: Reeza- Thank you for the help on this !!

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Tom :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a numeric format. Hope this helps you

```
proc format;
   value ACCDNWRK_FMT
      -1 = '-1 INAPPLICABLE'
       1  = '1 YES'
       2  = '2 NO'
       3  = '3 DOES NOT WORK'
;
run;

data example_ds;
FORMAT ACCDNWRK ACCDNWRK_FMT.;
input accdnwrk;
datalines;
1
2
3
-1
;
```

Comment: Your code is creating a numeric format and then trying to attach it to a character variable.

Comment: Tom and Draycut --Thank you !!